# Why Rectangle.Fill Multibinding is not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to create a simple WPF app where you are setting the **RGB** color (through 3 sliders-one per channel) and the resulted color to fill a `Rectangle`.

For sure that's possible by just using XAML and since I want to provide the `Rectangle.Fill` from three different values I used an `IMultiValueConverter` for the binding.

```cs
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(ExtractColorFrom(values));
        }

        private Color ExtractColorFrom(object[] values)
        {
            byte red = System.Convert.ToByte((double)values[0]);
            byte green = System.Convert.ToByte((double)values[1]);
            byte blue = System.Convert.ToByte((double)values[2]);
            Color color = new Color();
            color.R = red;
            color.G = green;
            color.B = blue;
            return color;
        }
```

The binding does not work for the `Rectangle.Fill` though. Is there something wrong with the XAML?

```xml
<Window ...>

    <Window.Resources>
        <view_model:RgbToBrushConverter x:Key='rgb_converter'/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>

        <Rectangle Width='300'
                   Height='190'
                   Stroke='Black'
                   StrokeThickness='1'
                   Margin='0 0 0 10'>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <MultiBinding Converter='{StaticResource rgb_converter}'>
                    <Binding ElementName='slider_red' Path='Value' Mode='OneWay'/>
                    <Binding ElementName='slider_green' Path='Value' Mode='OneWay'/>
                    <Binding ElementName='slider_blue' Path='Value' Mode='OneWay'/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment='Center'
                   Margin='5'
                   FontSize='20'>
            Per channel: 
            <Run Text='R'
                 Foreground='Red' />
            <Run Text='{Binding ElementName=slider_red, Path=Value}' />
            <Run Text='R'
                 Foreground='Green' />
            <Run Text='{Binding ElementName=slider_green, Path=Value}' />
            <Run Text='R'
                 Foreground='Blue' />
            <Run Text='{Binding ElementName=slider_blue, Path=Value}' />
        </TextBlock>

        <Slider x:Name='slider_red'
                Minimum='0'
                Maximum='255'
                Background='Red'
                Width='255'
                Margin='4'
                IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
                TickFrequency="1" />

        <Slider x:Name='slider_green'
                Minimum='0'
                Maximum='255'
                Background='Green'
                Width='255'
                Margin='4'
                IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
                TickFrequency="1" />

        <Slider x:Name='slider_blue'
                Minimum='0'
                Maximum='255'
                Background='Blue'
                Width='255'
                Margin='4'
                IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
                TickFrequency="1" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Run Text='R'  x 3 ?  Text='G' , 'B' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify your IMultiValueConverter implementation.

You could use Color.FromRgb(red, green, blue);

Works for me!

```
public class RgbToBrushConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public RgbToBrushConverter()
    {

    }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var x = ExtractColorFrom(values);
        return new SolidColorBrush(x);
    }

    private Color ExtractColorFrom(object[] values)
    {
        byte red = System.Convert.ToByte((double)values[0]);
        byte green = System.Convert.ToByte((double)values[1]);
        byte blue = System.Convert.ToByte((double)values[2]);
        return Color.FromRgb(red, green, blue);
    }

    ///MUST!!!!!
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[image]

And check Text='R' x 3 ? Text='G' , 'B' ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mate. What do you mean by `Text='R' x 3 ? Text='G' , 'B' ?`? Should I put it in the markup?

Comment: Great! In "per channel" you set R always. Check your question.